# Reading JPEG header file in c

Tags: c, header, height, width, jpeg

I have written a program in C to read JPEG file as given below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jpeglib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    int height,width,pixel_size;

    FILE *infile = fopen("/home/dbsl/Desktop/Anu/index.jpg", "rb");

    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
   jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);
   jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
   jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

   width = cinfo.output_width;
   height = cinfo.output_height;
   pixel_size = cinfo.output_components;
   printf("Width = %d",width);
   printf("height = %d",height);

   return(1);
}
```

The program is compiled successfully on Fedora20. But when run executed file it gives following error:

./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I dont understand what is the problem.

Comment: `No such file or directory` which part you don;t understand?

Answer (score 0):

Your program use a shared library (*libjpeg.so.9*). When you run your program, this library is loaded by `ld.so(8)`. So you have to have this file where `ld.so(8)` will try to find it.

See `man ld.so` to see where to put this file (default path are */lib* and */usr/lib*).

Comment: I tried this but still its not working. But now the problem is solved.